# Is there any free Magento 2 payment gateway extension

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Is there any free Magento 2 payment extension, which supports American Express Card payment? And in the back-end option, there is a sandbox setting.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for payment extension that supports "American Express Card" :

1. PX Shopping Cart
   https://marketplace.magento.com/px-pxpay2.html
2. Square Payments
   https://marketplace.magento.com/openprofessionalgroup-square.html